How do I get VS Code to apply my UI layout across all workspaces?
When creating a custom UI layout in VS Code, it doesn't seem to apply across all workspaces. So, when opening a new folder, the layout resets to default, and the custom layout only applies to whichever workspace it was created in. I'd like to create a custom layout that auto applies across all workspaces. How do I do this?
I built my custom layout by dragging views between different panels and rearranging them to my liking, but then when opening a different workspace none of the changes applied. I've tried searching through the settings to see if I had any weird option set, but didn't see anything. I'd like for my custom layout to apply to all workspaces.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/profiles

VS Code Profiles solved my problem perfectly! All I did was create a profile and apply that to each new workspace I created.
